# Android emulator PlatformException(load_failed_ad, cannot reload a failed ad, id=571273309, null)

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-admob

I included ads in my Flutter project. When I click "Load ads" button first time on Android emulator ad loads and shows perfectly. But when I close the ad and click "Load ads" button again I get this exception:

I/flutter ( 1549): InterstitialAd event MobileAdEvent.closed
D/DynamitePackage( 1549): Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
I/Ads ( 1549): This request is sent from a test device.
W/flutter ( 1549): onAdFailedToLoad: 3
I/Ads ( 1549): Ad failed to load : 3
I/flutter ( 1549): InterstitialAd event MobileAdEvent.failedToLoad
E/flutter ( 1549): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(load_failed_ad, cannot reload a failed ad, id=571273309, null)

Flutter doctor:

[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.418], locale en-US)
• Flutter version 1.9.1+hotfix.6 at C:\Users\olgam\source\flutter
• Framework revision 68587a0916 (9 weeks ago), 2019-09-13 19:46:58 -0700
• Engine revision b863200c37
• Dart version 2.5.0

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\olgam\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
• Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
• Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin version 41.0.2
• Dart plugin version 191.8593
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)

[√] Connected device (2 available)
• SM G930U • d77c5f0b • android-arm64 • Android 8.0.0 (API 26)
• Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)

• No issues found!

Here is my code:

```
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String _locale;

  MainPage(this._locale);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MainPageState();
  }
}

class MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  InterstitialAd _interstitialAd;
  static const MobileAdTargetingInfo targetingInfo = MobileAdTargetingInfo(
      childDirected: true, keywords: ['Games', 'Puzzles', 'Kids']);

  InterstitialAd buildInterstitial() {
    return InterstitialAd(
      adUnitId: Constants.UNIT_ID,
      targetingInfo: targetingInfo,
      listener: (MobileAdEvent event) {
        print("InterstitialAd event $event");
        if (event == MobileAdEvent.failedToLoad) {
          _interstitialAd.load();
        } else if (event == MobileAdEvent.closed) {
          _interstitialAd = buildInterstitial()..load();
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: Constants.APP_ID);
    _interstitialAd = buildInterstitial()..load();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _interstitialAd?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Kids Development'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Load ads'),
              onPressed: () {
                //print('--------trying to build interstitial');
                //_interstitialAd = buildInterstitial();
                _interstitialAd
                  ..load()
                  ..show();
              },
            )
       );
   }
}
```

This happens only with real ad unit id. If I use InterstitialAd.testAdUnitId everythins works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your ad is failing to load due to fill issues. From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest#ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL) Error code 3 means request was sent but no ad was returned due to lack of inventory(Check out your AdMob reports for match rate). Check back after sending more ad requests

this usually happens with new accounts/ad unit IDs. I do not understand why it keeps happening on the emulator since Google should just send test ads -_-

Comment: In my opinion there should be two levels of testAds, one "locally" not querying internet, one full live as it will fail, and you are stuck designing in the correct way...

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was with Blocking controls which I set in AdMob console. I made them less strict and now everything works fine.

Comment: how did you do that?